# How to append an entry to a relationalbone from Code in ViUR

Tags: python, viur

How can I add a new entry to a relationalbone from Python backend code?

Here the link to the framework: https://github.com/viur-framework/viur-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a relation from code to relationalBone can be done with the `setBoneValue` function:

```
skeleton.relation.setBoneValue(skeleton, "relation", keyObj, True)
```

The `keyObj` is a `db.Key` (the key from the other skeleton to be referenced) and the last parameter allows to append the relation data instead of replacing the whole relation data.